# How to import saved ML model on Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, machine-learning

I saved a linear regression model locally, which I want to use in later applications.

How can I import and call a saved model which was not created in the current application?

I'm using Scala on IntelliJ.

This is how I saved the model:

```
LRmodel.write.save(ORCpath+"LinearRegModel")
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to load the model, you need to have defined the same model prior. So it is not straight forward to load the model in a new environment.

ie. You cannot load a model which contain 4 nodes into a model which contains 10.

You can see here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression
That the method to load is:

```
val sameModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load(
   sc,
   "target/tmp/scalaLogisticRegressionWithLBFGSModel"
)
```

Comment: Update: I was able to load it as mentioned above, but when I try to use that model and transform the new dataset, it shows error on transform, it says 'cannot resolve symbol transform'.  Here is the code that I have used    
`val model = LinearRegressionModel.load(spark.sparkContext, "path/lrmodel")`
`val results = model.transform(newDF).toDF()`

Answer (score 0):

Different application isn't a problem. You can simply load through the save path as per @Wonay's instruction.

The issue is when you move to another file system, say a move from local to Hadoop...or just to another local PC. In this case, frankly, it is best to just regenerate the model on your new filesystem.